# How to make randomize text appear when play collides with rectangle

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

As the title says I'm trying make it so that when my player collides with my rectangle/Point class, It will make one of my 5 words appear like "Cool" or "Nice". The problem that I'm having is that I'm trying to make it so that one of the words will randomly appear, but I'm not sure how to make it so that it draws one of them randomly. I have tried using the randomizer to make it draw one of my words but I'm not sure on how to make it so that it will randomize my words then chose one of them to draw each time it collides with my rectangle/Point class.

This is the words  I'm using

```
font = pygame.font.Font("img/Snow.ttf",60)
text3 = font.render("Cool",True,(0,0,220))
textRect3 = text.get_rect()
textRect3.center = ((250,120))

font = pygame.font.Font("img/Bubble.ttf",60)
text4 = font.render("AWESOME",True,(145,0,145))
textRect4 = text.get_rect()
textRect4.center = ((250,120))

font = pygame.font.Font("img/Bubble.ttf",60)
text5 = font.render("AMAZING",True,(200,200,0))
textRect5 = text.get_rect()
textRect5.center = ((250,120))

font = pygame.font.Font("img/Bubble.ttf",60)
text6 = font.render("UNIMAGINABLE",True,(250,165,0))
textRect6 = text.get_rect()
textRect6.center = ((250,120))

font = pygame.font.Font("img/Blazed.ttf",60)
text7 = font.render("FIRE",True,(220,0,0))
textRect7 = text.get_rect()
textRect7.center = ((250,120))
```

This is my full code

```
import pygame,random
pygame.init()

width = 500
height = 600
# Screen width and height
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
# Name of the Screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
# The background


# player class
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.JumpCount = False
        self.isJump = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)
        
# Point class
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 3
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


# Color
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
# Calss's cords,size, and color
playerman = Player(200,250,40,40,white)

point1 = Point(400,300,40,70,white)
point2 = Point(770,300,40,70,white)

# All my list
points = [point1,point2]

# Point system
font = pygame.font.Font("img/CAT.ttf",60)
score = 0
text = font.render(""+str(score), True,(255,255,255))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = ((250,60))

font2 = pygame.font.Font("img/Bubble.ttf",60)
text2 = font2.render("NICE",True,(0,200,0))
textRect2 = text.get_rect()
textRect2.center = ((250,120))

font3 = pygame.font.Font("img/Snow.ttf",60)
text3 = font3.render("Cool",True,(0,0,220))
textRect3 = text.get_rect()
textRect3.center = ((250,120))

font4 = pygame.font.Font("img/Bubble.ttf",60)
text4 = font4.render("AWESOME",True,(145,0,145))
textRect4 = text.get_rect()
textRect4.center = ((250,120))

font5 = pygame.font.Font("img/Bubble.ttf",60)
text5 = font5.render("AMAZING",True,(200,200,0))
textRect5 = text.get_rect()
textRect5.center = ((250,120))

font6 = pygame.font.Font("img/Bubble.ttf",60)
text6 = font6.render("UNIMAGINABLE",True,(250,165,0))
textRect6 = text.get_rect()
textRect6.center = ((250,120))

font7 = pygame.font.Font("img/Blazed.ttf",60)
text7 = font7.render("FIRE",True,(220,0,0))
textRect7 = text.get_rect()
textRect7.center = ((250,120))


words = [text5,text7]

# Displaying class's in main loop
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

    # Drawing my classes and other things
    playerman.draw()

    for Point in points:
        Point.draw()
    window.blit(text,textRect)



# Making point get off screen
Ptimer = 0
Ptimer2 = 0
# for playing sprite when player jumps
Jumping = 0
spcdown = False
fps = 35
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    # Making the rectangles get off the screen for a short amount of time
    if Ptimer > 0:
        Ptimer += 1
        point1.y = -200
        point1.rect.topleft = (point1.x, point1.y)
    if Ptimer >= 15:
        Ptimer = 0
        

    if Ptimer2 > 0:
        Ptimer2 += 1
        point2.y = -200
        point2.rect.topleft = (point2.x, point2.y)
    if Ptimer2 >= 20:
        Ptimer2 = 0
        
    for Point in points:
        Point.x -= Point.speed
    for Point in points:
        if Point.x <= -200:
            Point.x = 550
            Point.y = 300


    #The player collideing with the point's
    if playerman.rect.colliderect(point1.rect):
        Ptimer += 1
        score += 1
        text = font.render(""+str(score), True,(255,255,255))
        

    if playerman.rect.colliderect(point2.rect):
        Ptimer2 += 1
        score += 1
        text = font.render(""+str(score), True,(255,255,255))
        
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


    if not keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        spcdown = False  # space released
    
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        Jumping = 1
        if not spcdown:
            spcdown = True
        
        

    collide = False

    playerman.y += playerman.speed
    # bird moving
    if not playerman.isJump:
        # [...]

        # the bird is allowed to jump even if it is not colliding:
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            playerman.isJump = True

        if collide:
            playerman.fall = 0

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount > 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
            
            # if K_SPACE is pressed, then the bird keeps jumping
            if not keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = False


    
    
    redrawwindow()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Perhaps a little heavy on the `minimum reproducible example`?  :)

Comment: What is the `randomizer` that you refer to?

Comment: I updated the question, and I'm trying to make it every single time that the player collides with the hitbox it will make one of my fonts show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `random` modules `choice` method.
You pass the a list of the words required and to the method, like such

```py
import random

words = ["Nice", "Cool", ..more words] 
random_word = random.choice(words)  # Will return a random element from the list
```